# dsPIC33 Fcy is half the desired frequency

Tags: pic, oscillator, microchip

I'm working on a `dsPIC33EP64GS502` trying to make it work at 70 MIPS with the internal oscillator. This is my code:

```
// FSEC
#pragma config BWRP = OFF               // Boot Segment Write-Protect bit (Boot Segment may be written)
#pragma config BSS = DISABLED           // Boot Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than BWRP))
#pragma config BSEN = OFF               // Boot Segment Control bit (No Boot Segment)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GSS = DISABLED           // General Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than GWRP))
#pragma config CWRP = OFF               // Configuration Segment Write-Protect bit (Configuration Segment may be written)
#pragma config CSS = DISABLED           // Configuration Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than CWRP))
#pragma config AIVTDIS = OFF            // Alternate Interrupt Vector Table bit (Disabled AIVT)

// FBSLIM
#pragma config BSLIM = 0x1FFF           // Boot Segment Flash Page Address Limit bits (Boot Segment Flash page address  limit)

// FSIGN

// FOSCSEL (Select Internal FRC at POR)
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Oscillator Source Selection (Fast RC Oscillator)
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Disabled

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = ON            // OSC2 Pin is I/O
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration bit (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECME           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are enabled)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Enable Bit (Clock switch will wait for the PLL lock signal)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF              // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT and SWDTEN disabled)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Timer Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC1 and PGED1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)
#pragma config BTSWP = OFF              // BOOTSWP Instruction Enable/Disable bit (BOOTSWP instruction is disabled)

// FDEVOPT
#pragma config PWMLOCK = OFF            // PWMx Lock Enable bit (PWM registers may be written without key sequence)
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C1 Pin bit (I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config ALTI2C2 = OFF            // Alternate I2C2 Pin bit (I2C2 mapped to SDA2/SCL2 pins)
#pragma config DBCC = OFF               // DACx Output Cross Connection bit (No Cross Connection between DAC outputs)

// FALTREG
#pragma config CTXT1 = OFF              // Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 1 bits (Not Assigned)
#pragma config CTXT2 = OFF              // Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 2 bits (Not Assigned)

// FBTSEQ
#pragma config BSEQ = 0xFFF             // Relative value defining which partition will be active after device Reset; the partition containing a lower boot number will be active (Boot Sequence Number bits)
#pragma config IBSEQ = 0xFFF            // The one's complement of BSEQ; must be calculated by the user and written during device programming. (Inverse Boot Sequence Number bits)

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <pps.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {      
    PLLFBD = 74;                        // M = PLLFBD + 2 = 76
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;             // N2 = 2
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;              // N1 = 2

    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);
    while(OSCCONbits.COSC != 0);
    while(OSCCONbits.LOCK != 1);

    ACLKCONbits.FRCSEL = 1;
    ACLKCONbits.SELACLK = 1;
    ACLKCONbits.APSTSCLR = 7;
    ACLKCONbits.ENAPLL = 1;
    while(ACLKCONbits.APLLCK != 1);

    INTCON1bits.NSTDIS = 0;

    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB5 = 1;
    while(1){
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 0;
        LATBbits.LATB5= 1;
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So basically I set `M=76`, `N1=2` and `N2=2` that should give me 70 MIPS with FRC at 7.37 MHz. I'm toggling RB5, I checked the generated assembler and it's a single instruction:

[image]

And this is the signal I see on my scope (sorry for the bad quality picture):

[image]

The signal period is 57.6ns and the period should be `(1/70e6) * 2 = 28.5ns` which is half the period I'm seeing so the dsPIC seems to be running at 35 MIPS, not 70 MIPS. What's wrong with the code? I even copied some code from Microchip example and I always get half the frequency.

The dsPIC is powered with `VDD = 3.3V` and `AVDD = 3.3V` and `VCAP = 10uF`. I'm working with MPLABX v3.61 and XC16 v1.31. I previously worked with `dsPICs` up to 40 MIPS and never encountered such an issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the datasheet clearly states that `FCY = FOSC/2`...

Comment: @DigitalNinja yes, but with those PLL settings I should be getting FOSC = 140 MHz

Comment: Okay, yep you're right

Comment: You've probably already seen this but here it is anyway: http://microchipdeveloper.com/16bit:osc-pll-140mhzpll and http://www.microchip.com/forums/m903847.aspx

Comment: Ok, apparently this is because LATB is a non-CPU SFR so the `BSET` and `BCLR` instructions take 2 cycles instead of 1, that explains everything.

Comment: So much for the one cycle read-modify-write of the 40MIPS dsPics, a branch is 4 cycles on the 70MIPS series...

Comment: @sstobbe that's surprising, I though the core was the same, you learn something new every day!

Comment: Another useful thing to check your fcy is output the clock to any of your PPS pin on this family.

Comment: Something similar just tripped me up on some code I was working on for a dsPIC30F4011.  I have a 8Mhz oscillator on the board, and was only getting 2Mhz in the code.  Then I remembered that because of the pipe lining the instruction clock was always /4, and this has held true on every PIC Iv'e programmed from the 16F54 upwards.  Once I configured the PLL for x4 mode, that brought my instruction clock back up to match the actual crystal speed.